# Depents on the declared values,List the records

Tags: sql, t-sql

```
declare @BranchId int
declare @PaymentDate date

set @DebtIsPayed =null
set @BranchId =3
set @PaymentDate='2013-01-01'

select og.StudentId, og.Name,sb.BranchName,bt.DeptValue,DebtIsPayed,PaymentDate ,bt.DebtDescriptionName
from StudentPayment od 
left outer join DebtDescription bt  on od.DebtDescriptionId= bt.DebtDescriptionId
left outer join Student og on od.StudentId= og.StudentId
left outer join Branch sb on sb.BranchId = og.BranchId
where od.DebtIsPayed=@DebtIsPayed and og.BranchId=@BranchId
```

I have a query something like this,variables come from the form element(asp.net app).
what I wanna do is if those declared variables is null,list all student payments,
if variable is set the a value (for example @DebtIsPayed=1),list all student without consedering their branch.but  if it is also set branchId ,list the all student in this branch and  @DebtIsPayed=1.
if it is set also the value date(@PaymentDate), list all record payed the after this date, 
I guess I can do it  with case,and for all variation,I can  create a query,but is there better or  easy way to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like

```
where ( 
   (@BranchID is null and od.DebtIsPayed=@DebtIsPayed)
or (@DebtIsPayed is null and og.BranchId=@BranchId)
) and (@PaymentDate is null or PaymentDate > @PaymentDate )
```

Comment: hmmm,so in your case,I should describe all variation inside the where cluase or for example (@DebtIsPayed is null and @BranchId is null) which list all list.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to do it without case operator. Here is the sample query:

```
declare @BranchId int
declare @PaymentDate date

set @DebtIsPayed =null
set @BranchId =3
set @PaymentDate='2013-01-01'

select og.StudentId, og.Name,sb.BranchName,bt.DeptValue,DebtIsPayed,PaymentDate ,bt.DebtDescriptionName
from StudentPayment od 
left outer join DebtDescription bt  on od.DebtDescriptionId= bt.DebtDescriptionId
left outer join Student og on od.StudentId= og.StudentId
left outer join Branch sb on sb.BranchId = og.BranchId
where (@DebtIsPayed IS NULL OR od.DebtIsPayed=@DebtIsPayed) AND (@BranchId IS NULL OR og.BranchId=@BranchId)
```

Note the where statement, if a paramter is null it is not considered in the query, if the parameter has a value, it will enfroce it

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
select og.StudentId, og.Name,sb.BranchName,bt.DeptValue,DebtIsPayed,PaymentDate ,bt.DebtDescriptionName
from StudentPayment od
left outer join DebtDescription bt  on od.DebtDescriptionId= bt.DebtDescriptionId
left outer join Student og on od.StudentId= og.StudentId
left outer join Branch sb on sb.BranchId = og.BranchId
where (od.DebtIsPayed = @DebtIsPayed or @DebtIsPayed is null) and (og.BranchId = @BranchId or @BranchId is null)
```

if parameter is missing it will retrieve all students with any value.